# Color of a widget inside a Stack is always slightly transparent

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I display a custom-made bottom app bar in a `Stack` because of keyboard padding reasons. The custom widget is fully opaque as it should be until it's a child of a `Stack` in which case, the content behind it starts to be visible since the color's opacity somehow changes.

[image: Bottom app bar color not fully opaque]

As you can see, it's only the "main" color that's transparent. Icons remain opaque.

This is the `build` method of my custom `BottomBar` widget which is then just regularly put into a `Stack`. I have tried using a `Material` and even a simple `Container` in place of the `BottomAppBar` widget but the results are the same.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return BottomAppBar(
    color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(1),
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(MdiIcons.plusBoxOutline),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        Text('Edited 11:57'),
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(MdiIcons.dotsVertical),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: what result you are expecting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you interact with the BottomAppBar ? It looks like an order problem. Try to put the BottomAppBar as last in the Stack children.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `BottomAppBar` doesn't have a constant size, if you did not add it to `Scaffold` `bottomNavigationBar` named parameter has a size if this is not `null`. Below is peace of code in `Scaffold` dart file:

```
double bottomNavigationBarTop;
if (hasChild(_ScaffoldSlot.bottomNavigationBar)) {
  final double bottomNavigationBarHeight = layoutChild(_ScaffoldSlot.bottomNavigationBar, fullWidthConstraints).height;
  bottomWidgetsHeight += bottomNavigationBarHeight;
  bottomNavigationBarTop = math.max(0.0, bottom - bottomWidgetsHeight);
  positionChild(_ScaffoldSlot.bottomNavigationBar, Offset(0.0, bottomNavigationBarTop));
}
```

You can even develop your own `Widget` without `BottomAppBar` but if you want things like `centerDocked` and things like circular notched, you will have to do more stuff (anyway you have flexibility to custom design the way you want).

Here is a simple example to do that(one way to do that):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomBottomBar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
            color: Colors.greenAccent, // if you want this color under bottom bar add the margin to list view
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 100,
              itemBuilder: (_, int index) => Text("Text $index"),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.amber.withOpacity(.5),
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: 50,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: List.generate(4, (int index) => Text("Text $index")), // you can make these clickable by wrapping with InkWell or any gesture widget
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```